# CSS color variables - at-rule or selector expected whilst defining CSS colors

Tags: css

Hi I am having the following issue:

"at-rule or selector expected whilst defining CSS colors."

I am using VS code and I have checked the CSS at https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator#css

I dont know what the issue is here!

[image: CSS CODE]

[image: VALIDATED]

```
    /* Color Variables */
$red: red;
$green: green;
$orange: orange;
$blue: blue;
$purple: purple;
$white: white;
$black: black;
$bg: /* #eff3f6 */ #e3e5e6;
$darkgray-blue: #354052;
$lightgray-blue: #7f8fa4;

/* Styles */
body {
  background: $bg;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.text-red {color: $red !important;}
.text-green {color: $green !important;}
.text-orange {color: $orange !important;}
.text-blue {color: $blue !important;}

/* buttons */
.btn-red {
  background: $red;
  color: $white;
  font-size: xx-small;
  &:hover, &:focus {
    background: darken($red, 8%);
    color: white;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The CSS validator seems to have some kind of bug. If you remove either the spaces before the `/* Color Variables */` comment or the comment itself, it will show you errors – as it should, because this isn’t CSS.

You’re using [Sass](https://sass-lang.com/) variables, rule syntax, and functions. You should name your file `style.scss` instead of `style.css` to indicate your intent to most tools, and if you haven’t configured a Sass build, you’ll need to do that. How specifically depends on the rest of your tooling, but one way or another, there’ll be a plugin (e.g. [sass-loader for webpack](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/)).

Answer (score 0):

If you ask about css variables use:

```css
:root{
 --color-red: red;
}
.class{
  color: var(--color-red);
}
```

If you ask about scss(sass) variables, try to use interpolation:

```scss
$red: red;

.class{
  color: #{$red};
}
```

Read about [interpolation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/interpolation)

**But i think problem that you use scss inside css file**